# How can i fix TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
module.exports = {
name: 'binfo',
description: 'Bot info',
caategory: 'info',

execute(message, args){
    const Discord = require('discord.js')
    const bot = new Discord.Client()
     const binfo = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Bot Information")
.addField("Bot Name :", bot.user.name)
.addField("Version : ", version)
.addField("Created By :", '')
.addField('Servers with this bot :', bot.guilds.size)
.addImage('')
.addField("Created At : ", bot.user.createdAt)
.addField("Commands :", "For More Commands Check Text Channel commands-guide")
.setTimestamp()
.setColor("#3d5eff")
.setThumbnail(bot.user.displayAvatarURL)




}
}
```

I know it cant read the name for some reason. Is it username or even something else? If you know let me know thanks.

Comment: If an answer solves your question, then accept it to let others know what worked and that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as

```
<client>.user.name
```

the correct one is:

```
<client>.user.username
```

Please [read](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=username)